# What special member function is used for copy initialization in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, c++17, copy-constructor

I'm testing c++ class initialization.

```
class Point
{
private:
    int x,y;
public:
    Point() = delete;
    Point(int a):x(a), y(0) { std::cout << "Conversion" << std::endl;}
    
    Point(const Point&) { std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;}
    //Point(const Point&) = delete;
    Point& operator=(const Point&) = delete;

    Point(Point&&) = delete;
    Point& operator=(Point&&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    Point p1(5); //case1
    Point p2 = 5; //case2

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, I thought "5" will be converted to a temp object by conversion constructor for both case1/2 at first. And then, I expected that copy constructor must be used for initializing of p1 & p2. But, it was not.
When I run this code, I saw just two "Conversion" message in console. No "Copy Constructor" message.

Even though, I deleted all copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator and move assignment operator, this code worked well.

I would appreciate if you let me know what special member function will be used for initializing after creating temp object for "5",

I am using g++ compiler with std=c++17 option.

Comment: Your copy constructor does not make copies as it fails to copy `x` and `y` members, thus it is buggy.  Don't code stub copy constructors, assignment operators, etc.  If you write such functions, complete them.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Thank you for appropriate tag.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes you're right. This code is incomplete. I just want to check the behavior of constructor. But I will heed your advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Case I

In case 1 the **converting constructor** is used since you have provided a constructor that can convert an `int` to `Point`. This is why this constructor is called converting constructor.

##### Case II

From [mandatory copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are **required to omit** the copy and move construction of class objects, even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The objects are **constructed directly into the storage** where they would otherwise be copied/moved to. The **copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible**:

> In the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is a **prvalue** of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the variable type.

In case 2, even if you `delete` copy/move constructor only the converting constructor will be used. This is due to **mandatory copy elison**(in *C++17*) as quoted above.

Comment: According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) in the case of copy initialization even when the elision takes place, the appropriate constructor is required to be accessible. This doesn't appear to match the observed behavior where deleting both the copy and move constructors still allows the elision to take place. EDIT: Oops, I didn't realize that passage had the "(until C++17)" tag and reflected the pre-mandatory elision rules.

Comment: @Anoop Rana Thank you for your answer. In my opinion, this copy elision looks very similar to RVO. I thought this mandatory copy elision would be available from C++17, so I tested the same code at c++14. When I compiled this code with std=c++14 option, finally I got  an error by deleted function of Point(Point &&). 
But there was very weird thing. I've defined the move constructor as `Point(Point&&) { std::cout << "Move constructor" << std::endl;}`, and the compilation completed. But when I run the code, I was still able to see 2 "Conversion" messages.

Comment: @bugcreator You still see 2 "Conversion" because compilers before C++17 were *allowed to construct directly into storage*. Note the word `allowed to` in my previous sentence. This **doesn't mean** they were *required to*.  So, practically most of the compilers(before C++17) used to elude the copy/move construction because they were allowed to. On the other hand, in C++17 they are *required to* .

Comment: I thought this is the case @Nathan Pierson mentioned. Although, Move Constructor was elisioned, but it must be accessible in c++14.